# Reading N-Quads in Jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena, apache-jena

I'm trying to read an N-Quads file with Jena, but all I get is **an empty model**. The file I'm trying to read is taken from the example in N-Quads [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/):
`<http://example.org/#spiderman> <http://www.perceive.net/schemas/relationship/enemyOf> <http://example.org/#green-goblin> <http://example.org/graphs/spiderman> .`
(I saved it as a file named file.nq).

The way I'm loading the model is using the `RDFDataMgr`. But it didn't work with `Model.read` either.

`RDFDataMgr.loadModel("file.nq", Lang.NQUADS)`
yields an empty model.

What am I missing? Doesn't Jena support N-Quads out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Jena supports N-Quads. Try loadDataset.

N-Quads is for multiple graphs and you have read it into one graph.  What you get is just the default graph triples, in this case, none.

There is a warning emitted:

`WARN  riot                      :: Only triples or default graph data expected : named graph data ignored`

If you didn't get that then (1) you are running an old copy (2) you have turned logging off (3) the file is empty.